# Algorithm if there is a string including subsequences A and B but not F

Tags: algorithm, subsequence

I'm looking for an efficient alogrithm for the following problem:

We are given as input three strings A, B and F and we need to tell if there is a String X such that A and B are subsequences of X but F is not. The output of the algorithm should be "Yes" or "No".

A subsequence of a string is any string that can be created by removing some letters from the original string, without changing the order of the remaining letters.

For example if A = "aabab", B = "bbaa" and F = "baba", the algorithm should output "Yes", because "aabbaab" has A and B as a subsequence but not F.

Any ideas?

Comment: Even KMP/Needle in the Stack can do that!

Comment: Could you please clarify how KMP could be applied to this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) for KPM. Looks good

Comment: I was thinking about finding the longest common subsequence first. In the example case that would be "ba". Then considering the Strings A2 and B2 which we get by removing this longest subsequence from both, which would leave us with A2 = "aab" and B2 = "ba" in the example. I'm not 100% sure if this leads to anything.

Comment: @tykkipeli Checking if a string is subsequence of another string doesn't need you to perform LCS at all. Run a loop for every string and check that string against `A`,`B` and `F`. You can perform some optimizations with string lengths etc.

Comment: Also, you won't need KMP here(as you know it) since you are dealing with a subsequence and not a substring.

Comment: I don't understand how KMP helps here. KMP is used for finding occurances of a string within another string. But this problem has to do with subsequences. The string X doesn't need to have A or B anywhere as a continuous substring but only as a subsequence.

Comment: "aabbaab" has subsequences "bbaa" and "aabab", but not "baba"

Comment: See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-two-strings-find-first-string-subsequence-second/

Comment: Oh you are correct Matt, my bad example

Comment: @tykkipeli I said you `won't need` KMP.

Comment: I know sorry, I wasn't talking to you. I couldnt see your message as I was typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I have thought a bit more about this problem I found a really simple and efficient solution. ;) This problem was really much easier than I first thought. It can be solved in linear **O(|A| + |B|)** time without any extra space.

The idea is to iterate through the characters of F and take always the maximal part of A and B to the supersequence so that no longer than the current prefix of F is a subsequence of it. The following c++ code clarifies the idea:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < F.size()-1; k++) {
    while (i < A.size() && A[i] != F[k]) i++;
    while (j < B.size() && B[j] != F[k]) j++;
    i++; j++;
    if (i >= A.size() && j >= B.size()) {
        cout << "YES";
        return 0;
    }
}
cout << "NO";
```

Answer (score 1):

Let **X** be a *minimal* supersequence of **A** and **B** if every letter of **X** can be matched to a letter of **A** and/or **B** in order.

Every supersequence of **A** and **B** is a supersequence of **F** if and only if every minimal supersequence of **A** and **B** is a supersequence of **F**.

A DFA that accepts minimal supersequences of **A** and **B** can be easily constructed with at most **|A|*|B|** states, with each state corresponding to a pair of compatible positions in both strings.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction

If there is a supersequence of **A** and **B** that is not a supersequence of **F**, then there is a path through this DFA that is not a supersequence of **F**.

Define the cost of a path through the DFA as the length of the longest prefix of **F** that is a subsequence of the path, i.e., the number of characters you would match from **F** along the path.

Then, since the DFA is acyclic, you can use Dijkstra's algorithm or best-first search to find the least cost to reach every state.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Iff any accepting state has a least cost that is less than **|F|**, then there is a supersequence of **A** and **B** that is not also a supersequence of **F**.

Complexity of the whole operation is **O(|A|*|B|)**

The simplest way to implement this is to use a **|A|+1** x **|B|+1** matrix as the DFA -- just like the one you use for the LCS calculation.  Each cell in the matrix is a state.  Fill the cells with their least cost when they are discovered.